# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

I have products inventory program and with modify products function in menu file

```
def modify_product(self):
    id = input("Enter product id: ")
    type = input("Enter product type: ")
    price = input("Enter product price: ")
    quantity = input("Enter product quantity: ")
    description = input("Enter product description: ")
    if type:
        self.inventor.modify_type(id, type)
    if price:
        self.inventor.modify_price(id, price)    
    if quantity:
        self.inventor.modify_quantity(id, quantity)   
    if description:
        self.inventor.modify_description(id, description)
```

I am getting error:`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'`

Here is my modify_type,price,quantity,description functions in file inventor.py:

```
def modify_type(self, product_id, type=''):
    self._find_product(product_id).type = type

def modify_price(self, product_id, price):
    self._find_product(product.id).price = price

def modify_quantity(self, product_id, quantity):
    self._find_product(product.id).quantity = quantity

def modify_description(self, product_id, quantity):
    self._find_product(product.id).description = description
```

Here is _find_product function:

```
def _find_product(self, product_id):
    for product in self.products:
        if str(product.id) ==(product.id):
            return product
        return None
```

Comment: Hint: What are you getting from `_find_product(product.id)` ?

Comment: I managed to divine where your error comes from, but next time do include the *full* traceback of your error, not just the exception itself.

Comment: trivial indentation mistake. you indented `return None` once too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self._find_product()` call is returning `None`, because you are not testing the correct value in the loop.

Don't test `str(product.id) against`product.id`but against the`product_id` argument:

```
if str(product.id) == product_id:
```

You are also returning `None` too early. That `return` statement is redundant, just remove it. If a function ends without a `return`, `None` is returned by default:

```
def _find_product(self, product_id):
    for product in self.products:
        if str(product.id) == product_id:
            return product
```

This can be collapsed into:

```
def _find_product(self, product_id):
    return next((p for p in self.products if str(p.id) == product_id), None)
```

Comment: thanks,maybe i need a database for saving products information or better to save in txt or excel file?

Comment: Perhaps. I cannot tell you with any degree of certainty without knowing your use cases, experience level, and environment. That's too broad a subject to answer in comments. :-)

Comment: Thanks for help,I think first i write all information to txt,maybe later i transfer this to database.P.s I am learning programming for 1 month